# Finding The Summation of N term

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, systems-of-equations

I have a  Two sequence  A and B which are in a serious  relationship which is as:
[image]

where $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = \sqrt{3}$

I have to find :

$a_k+b_k$ in general I came with this formula($a_n$ and $b_n$ are known.):

$a_k+b_k = (a_n+yb_n)\times({2}^{4k-2.5})$ where $k>n$

Is the above expression given by me is correct or not

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: $$
a_{n+j}+b_{n+j} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
4^j(a_n+b_n),\qquad\quad \mbox{ if } j \mbox{ is even};
\\
\dfrac{4^j}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigl(a_n+\sqrt{3}b_n\Bigr),\quad \mbox{ if } j \mbox{ is odd}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$